# laravel controllers methods injected with model or not?

Tags: laravel, function, model, controller, inject

Could someone explain which way is better and why ? :

a)

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    return view('user.profile', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

or

b)

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    return view('user.profile', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both, but if you plan that your code will grow, it's better the first.

Comment: But if i have userService and want to pass data from controller in a) case i will pas an $id and in case b) i can pass $user collection so both cases looks same to me and i am thinking about which to stay is better.

Comment: With the second you enforce the right class, so you can't accidentally pass a wrong class or even an unexpected integer.